# How to enable Apps in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have downloaded Google Chrome from [Dev channel](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?extra=devchannel) and opening chrome with a **--enable-apps** parameter but still cann't install google apps. Does anybody know how to install Chrome Apps in a chrome? 

 I have tried to install [this](http://andreevich.googlecode.com/files/calc_lite.crx) Chrome App which is called Calc Lite. This App has been developed just to see Chrome App in action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications are a special mode of running a website, not extensions. You can create one by clicking "Create Application Shortcuts" under the page menu (upper right-hand corner). When clicked, these launch the website without an address bar, bookmarks, or tab bar. It's designed to make ajax applications like Gmail, Google Calendar, or Google reader feel more like a desktop application than a website.

Extensions have been enabled for quite some time in chrome, and even the stable version supports them now. The extension in question seems to download and Chrome (6.0.422.0) Prompts to install it, though given no documentation I have not actually installed the extension since I don't know what exactly the code does. If you would like to see extensions in action, I would suggest looking at Google's [extension gallery](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/?hl=en).

You might've stumbled upon an application designed for Chrome OS. I wouldn't be able to say if the Chrome browser will ever support these.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor I blame google for the confusing naming scheme, but it appears you are correct in that there are now stand-alone extensions. These chrome "Applications" are not documented anywhere that I can find, and I'd suspect that they're for the new ChromeOS which should be coming out soon.

Comment: @MrStatic Yes, but the extension is using a new field named "launch" and if you try to install it, Chrome refuses while saying `Apps are not enabled.` This isn't a conventional feature that's been documented.